# Объясните как работает метод super,а так-же конструкция super().__init__() в python?

Tags: python, классы, методы

Объясните как работает метод `super`, а так-же конструкция `super().__init__()` в python? `super` часто используется в классах. Желательно объяснить как можно проще и на простых примерах.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4+super

Comment: Отличный ответ но гуглом я умею пользоваться.Читаю и разбираюсь но на данный момент понять не могу, сюда написал затем,что-бы может у кого нибудь получилось объяснить.

Comment: Raymond Hettinger - Super considered super! https://youtu.be/EiOglTERPEo

Comment: Нашёл такой же ролик только с русским переводом https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61UuKJRl2m0

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`super()` - это функция, которая обращается к классу, от которого наследуется текущий.

Сначала немного кода:

```py
class A:
    def some_method(self):
        print('Spam, eggs!!1')


class B(A):
    def some_method(self):
        print('Hello, World!')


x = B()
x.some_method()
```

*stdout:*

```html
Hello, World!
```

Как Вы можете заметить, мы перегрузили метод родительского класса. Но что, если нам потребуется всего лишь немного дополнить его? Как нам дополнить родительский метод, не копируя его полностью и не изобретая велосипедов? Тут нам и нужен `super()`:

```py
class A:
    def some_method(self):
        print('Spam, eggs!!1')


class B(A):
    def some_method(self):
        super().some_method()
        print('Hello, World!')


x = B()
x.some_method()
```

*stdout:*

```html
Spam, eggs!!1
Hello, World!
```

С помощью `super().some_method()` мы вызвали родительский метод, а после дополнили свой. Именно для этого чаще всего используется эта функция.

`__init__()` - это метод инициализации класса, следовательно `super().__init__()` вызывает метод инициализации из родительского класса. Например, чтобы дополнить его.